# Cloning the WPF ComboBox control: Ideas or suggestions

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, combobox, wpf-controls

If have a control that acts like a record selector from a database, say, for example, customers.

The **control** must act in certain ways **allowing the user to type** the name, the alias or the code of the customer, and the control will **select the correct one**, or **offer a list** of possible candidates, and other behaviors.

I have tried to inherit from `ComboBox`, but there are some `ComboBox` behaviors that make it difficult or impossible to do what I want, so I'm better starting from scratch, with a TextBox and Button.

**The questions are:**

- Do you know some open-source component so I don't have to start from zero?
- Have you already done something like this and want to share methodologies or tips?
- Am I good with a TextBox, a Button and a PopUp control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this control from CodeProject: [A Reusable WPF Autocomplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx)

It allows you to specify a source list, and a custom filter. In your custom filter you can select to show only those records that have a name, alias or code that fit the text entered, and the user will have a list of filtered options displayed to them.

Comment: great! And you are the author!